# typo3 extbase validate for multiple records

Tags: validation, typo3, extbase

I have written one extbase plugin, that creates the FE users from front end form.

The create action is something like this

```
/**
* action create
*
* @param \TYPO3\Usermanagement\Domain\Model\Users $newUsers
* @return void
*/
public function createAction(\TYPO3\Usermanagement\Domain\Model\Users $newUsers) {
    $this->usersRepository->add($newUsers);
}
```

Here I want to validate for same username or email already exists or not.
How can I do this ?
Any suggestions ?
Thank you.

Comment: What about regular expressions and pure PHP?

Comment: Also, you can write your own validator and refer to it in your model, something like "uniqueuser" . I'd put more details into an answer when I know more. I am creating one in our project right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to bind a `$newUser` as an action's param, instead you can just read some fields using `$this->request->hasArgument('something')` and  `$this->request->getArgument('something')` to validate properties yourself, and create new `user` object manually like.

```php
public function createAction() {
    $newUsers = new \TYPO3\Usermanagement\Domain\Model\Users();
    // do something with $newUsers object...
    $this->usersRepository->add($newUsers);
}
```

It will not throw an exception in case when there's no valid `user` object in the request, so it will allow you to handle form's error as you want/need.

It will also allow you to use some preprocessing before saving ie hashing/salting passwords.

Comment: check my edit, all you need is just create an object, and fill it with incoming data.

Comment: How to validate for captcha, if we use freeCap ?